# Session being set but not persisted

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

**Problem**

The `django.contrib.auth.login` function is succeeding, but the session does not seem to persist.

**Code**

I am creating my own set of functions to use with an AJAX client inside of my Django server.

I have the following code in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def auth_login(request):
    username = json.loads(request.body)['username']
    password = json.loads(request.body)['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({}, status=400)

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'auth/login/', auth_login, name='login')
]
```

**Details**

- As mentioned above, the call to `login()` succeeds. `request.session` is being set properly, and I can access if from within `auth_login`. On subsequent requests, `request.session` does not exist and `django.contrib.auth.get_user` returns `AnonymousUser`.
- (Possibly relevant) I am also using the seemingly-popular https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. This `urls.py` file is in an application that is per-tenant, so the user is actually authenticating on `tenantname.hostname.com/tenant/auth/login/`.
- The tenant's `django_session` table is being set correctly. For each attempted login, I can see `session_key`, `session_data`, and `expire_data`.
- The cookie for `tenantname.hostname.com` is empty after attempted logins.

I'm just out of ideas as to what other things I could try to lead me to a solution.

**Question(s)**

- Any thoughts as to why this session isn't actually saved into the cookie?

  *OR*
- Thoughts as to what else I could try that could lead me to a solution?

Comment: Is the client from which are you doing the requests in the same domain that the server?

Comment: Thanks for the thought @grouchoboy, but yeah it is the same domain.